# Multiplication and addition of Netcdf files

Tags: multiplication, netcdf, addition, netcdf4, cdo-climate

I have two timeseries netcdf files with the same number of steps:

1. **U.nc**  with variable name **u10.**
2. **V.nc**  with variable name **v10**.
   Now I want to add multiply U.nc with U.nc
   similarily, V.nc with V.nc.

**I also want to add U.nc with V.nc.**, the variables u10 and v10 should be added.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar answer to Adrian Tompkins's above.

```
cdo -L -expr,'wind=sqrt(u10*u10+v10*v10)' -merge u.nc v.nc uv.nc wind.nc
```

This uses method chaining. Depending on how CDO was built, you may or may not need `-L`.

Comment: What does the -L "lock" effectively do?  I sometimes get a segmentation fault when attempting to use chained commands (esp. on my desktop) - would this use of -L resolve that issue?

Comment: Issues are explained here: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki#Segfault-with-netcdf4-files. If the hdf5 library on your system is not threadsafe, you need to add - L for chaining to always work.

Comment: brilliant, thanks... I checked the documentation but there is not much detail on this option there.  This is great, I often had to rewrite code avoiding chaining due to the seg fault. thanks!

Comment: easy solution is to install CDO from conda. Everything is threadsafe that way. Installing hdf5 from source threadsafe seems to be a pain

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with CDO

Adding u with u:

```
cdo mul u.nc u.nc ubyu.nc
```

and

```
cdo ubyu.nc vbyv.nc usumv.nc
```

However it seems what you want to do is make the wind vector, for that you can merge the files and then use the expr operator

```
cdo merge u.nc v.nc uv.nc
cdo expr,'wind=sqrt(u10*u10+v10*v10)' uv.nc wind.nc
```

[See the tutorial here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Tutorial#The-expr-Operator) for more details on the the expr operator

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked. 
Sir can you help me in Bias Correction of the RCM Precipitation Data.

Comment: Best to upload this as a separate question on the appropriate site though

Comment: Thanks sir, but I have uploaded this question and nothing happened, question was also closed. Can you help me regarding this?